# Order and group in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a database as:

```
Serial no.  Name
1            A
1            B
2            Aa
2            Z
3            D
3            A
3            C
```

and I want the result as

```
Serial no.  Name
2            Aa
2            Z
1            A
1            B
3            D
3            A
3            C
```

I want each group (having same serial no.) to be sorted with other groups on the basis of the first name in the groups but inside the groups the order of name should remain unchanged.

I have tried doing

```
Select * From tablename
group by `Serial no.` 
order by `Name`
```

but I am getting :

```
Serial no.  Name
2            Aa
1            A
3            D
```

Comment: I am actually using python based dbms but these I have tested in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

This is the data from table:

```
SELECT * FROM #temp
```

[image]

```
Select *
from tablename
Order by Serial no DESC, Name;
```

This is the output that I obtained for following query:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I don't want serial no. decreasing what I want is to sort each group ( ie. they have same serial no.) by the first name in the group.

Comment: Poor sample data. Add (3,'D'), (3,'A') and (4,'C'), and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry I am not sure how to achieve this @AshutoshRawat. I will delete my answer.

Comment: @AshutoshRawat there is no aggregate function in this query so I don't think Group by can be used to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping on your table doesn't make sense at all. Order by would do just fine.

```
select Serialno,Name
from table _name
order by Name desc
```

Comment: It will give Aa A A B C D Z as answer

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do what you want with SQL.

You want the order within each serial number group to be the same as in the table, but there is no well defined order within a table.

A table in SQL is an unordered set of rows, and any order must be imposed by an `ORDER BY` clause. So unless your order can be expressed in SQL and does not depend on the physical placement of the rows in the table, your problem cannot be solved.

The order of rows in a table can change and is implementation dependent. For example, a reorganization might change it. In PostgreSQL, for example, a simple update changes the order, and you are not even guaranteed to get the same order in two sequential scans.

Comment: thanks, @laurenz but I want the order in which they are mentioned in a group(same serial no.) to remain same only that the whole group gets sorted based on the first name, so I think the description is right. See in your solution it is changing order inside the group , if i have given D, A, C in serial no 3 then it should remain D,A,C always.

Comment: I have edited my description hope it helps and sorry for all the confusion, it's my first time here

Comment: Why, is some alternate solution possible?

Comment: Thanks, but I have found an alternate solution. I am doing group by and order by then storing them into another table and then with the help of it getting the desired result.

Comment: Still, there is no guarantee that you will get the rows in the order you entered them into the database. If that's good enough, fine.

Comment: Till now I am getting the desired result, if you have a better solution then plese share.